# SVG height in IE 11

Tags: html, css

I have a complex HTML code that I simplified here :

```
<label class="FancyInput">
  <input type="text">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 18" class="FancyInputBorder">
        <path d="M-1000,12 L223.166144,12 C217.241379,12 217.899687,12 225.141066,12"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 14 12" class="FancyInputCheck">
        <path d="M1 7 5.5 11 L13 1"></path>
    </svg>  
</label>

<style>
.FancyInputBorder {
    width:1200px;
    height:18px;
    display: inline;
}

.FancyInputCheck {
    width:14px;
    height:12px;
}
</style>
```

Basically the HTML doesn't render the same way in Chrome and IE 11. So I removed all non required code to illustrate the problem.

in Chrome FancyInputBorder has indeed the right height which is 18px but in IE 11 it doesn't.

Screen shot :

[image]

Can anyone help please ? Why IE 11 doesn't set the height of the SVG at 18 px as requested.

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: I can help if you show the SVG code.

Comment: Sorrym the code was already there but was not formatted as such and didn't appear. I corrected that.

Comment: Based on the HTML/CSS you provided, I'm seeing IE11 and Chrome rendering similar. https://i.imgur.com/NyOhKQg.png (Plunkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xjy8CWfNlYmmdqTz)

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer would be using the attribute `viewbox` and `preserveAspectRatio`.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 18" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
    <defs></defs>
    <g>
        <path d="whatever you have here"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It's also possible to set style on the svg tag => `style="width:1200px;height:18px;"` but in my experience this can be left out in most cases.
In most cases, remove the `width` and `height` attributes on the svg tag if you have any.
Depending on your code using the svg code inline, in CSS or as an img src, things might be different.

So a very general answer which can be reviewed, once you show some actual code that matters.